# Bootstrap grid doesn't sit side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here's a very basic 6 column grid that I'd like to sit side by side.  The second column breaks to the line under the first.

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="col-6">
        Col6
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        Col6
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap `cols` need to be inside a `row`. Replace the `col-12` class with `row` class, your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you put **col** inside **col** put **row** class in between

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      Col6
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Col6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```